# Age restriction on teams?

Tags: usability, user-research

My platform is a free online tool for sports clubs to administrate their organizations. I am currently struggling with some age restriction basics for teams and I would appreciate your input and help!

A user sets a minimum age to 18 on a team, but the club's rules state that a member can be 17 and join as long as he/she are 18 at a given date during the team's duration.
E.g. I have a basket team for youngsters between 18 and 23. It runs from January to July. To join, the members have to be 18 by the end of June.

The issue is related to the creation part of the process. The issue I'm having is on the admins part. How to intuitively make a set of input boxes etc. for the admin to setup the age boundaries for his/her club. How would the creation setup look for this? Or would you approach this differently? A minimum and maximum age with the option of selecting when the minimum age restriction should be met? Something totally different?

I just want to explore some options and hear your opinions on the matter!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'd approach this issue from the other side, namely knowing the duration of the team and its age restriction you can calculate the latest birth date of the participants of this team, e.g.

> The team A runs from **January till the end of June 2018** and you must be **18** not later than on June 30th, it means your birth date must be **June 30th, 2000** or earlier.
>
> The team B runs from **February till the end of August 2018** and you must be **18** not later than on August 31st, it means your birth date must be **August 31st, 2000** or earlier.

You request the players (participants) to register with they birth date and once they want to see which teams they may join, you show them only the teams where the latest allowable birth date is **later or equal** to their birth date, e.g.

> Participant 1 was born on **February 11th, 2000**, they may join both **A** and **B** teams.
>
> Participant 2 was born on **July 1st, 2000**, they may join only team **B**, as requirement for team **A** (**June 30th, 2000**) is earlier his birth date.

I hope it is clear to you.

---

### Edit after OP's information addition

If I understand you correctly, you are looking for some sort of "Create team" dialog, what about the following:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fV7spy.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Since the club rules are fixed, the birth dates of the participants can be calculated.
I assume that you may enter the lower age limit during the duration of the team, but you must stay below the upper age limit during the duration of the team.

Therefore, the yellow tooltip field changes its content when the age limits change and the start and end dates of the team change.

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: The issue is more related to the creation part of the process. I should have made that more clear in my original post! I will edit this in afterwards.

The issue I'm having is on the admins part. How to intuitively make a set of input boxes etc. for the admin to setup the age boundaries for his/her club. So my question is more, how would the creation setup look for this?

Comment: I've added some content to answer your question on creation part of the process.

Comment: In some sense, yes that is the basic thought behind the feature. But we still face the problem: What if a team has an age restriction of 18, but it is not at the team start, the age restriction must be met half way into the team's season (Your duration). What I'm looking for is your thoughts on how this could be solved in an intuitive matter.

Comment: @MartinCapion, what are the rules exactly? Once you state that age restriction must be met before starting the course, later that during the course. Anyway, for such mutually excluding options radio buttons or a drop-down are the most suitable solutions.

Answer (score 1):

> **Edit after your comment**

Why not simply create a dropdown on the admin side like:

**Minimum age required:**

[dropdown with ages between **x** and **y**]

*The participant must have this age by the end time of the club*

---

> **Original answer**

I would like to add something to Mike's answer, actually improve something :

> ..you show them only the teams where the latest allowable birth date is
>   later or equal to their birth date, e.g.

This isn't that great of an experience, think about this: two friends, one 19 and one 17 talk about it, the 19 year old invites his friend to join telling him where to find the team and all the details but since he's 17 and he doesn't turn 18 by the time it ends, he can't find it and reports a bug to the administrator or thinks there's something wrong on his side.

You **should** show all the teams but allow them to join only those that meet the rules. For the others you can remove the **join** button and display a message like "You cannot join this team due to age restrictions" or something like that.

Comment: The issue is more related to the creation part of the process. I should have made that more clear in my original post! I will edit this in afterwards.

The issue I'm having is on the admins part. How to intuitively make a set of input boxes etc. for the admin to setup the age boundaries for his/her club. So my question is more, how would the creation setup look for this?

Comment: @MartinCapion That sounds pretty simple, check out the edit in my answer.

Comment: Yeah and then again it's not simple at all. Right now we have two input fields "min age" and "max age". Some teams could set the minimum to be 18, but they want their members to just reach that minimum after 2 months (Just as an example). What I'm looking for is your thoughts on how this could be solved in an intuitive matter.